# Add a "Next Post" & "Previous Post" styled button manually to a post

Tags: php, css, previous, next

Can anyone walk me through the exact steps?

I want to create two buttons that sit next to each other at the bottom of a post for the NEXT and PREVIOUS posts...I want to be able to insert this manually (html), and using a style/class to do it.

I'm assuming I have to do something in the functions.php file first? Then create a custom CSS button? Then add the code in the bottom of my post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is standard WordPress functionality, contained in [`previous_post_link`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/previous_post_link) and [`next_post_link`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/next_post_link). You don't need to edit `functions.php`. Just add to your template:

```
<div class="buttons">
  <span class="previous-button"><?php previous_post_link() ?></span>
  <span class="next-button"><?php next_post_link() ?></span>
</div>
```

Now you can style the buttons with `css`. Follow the codex links for customizing options to the functions.